# ERROR: The IDbCommand and IDbConnection implementation in the assembly MySql.Data could not be found

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

Hy guys. How I resolve this problem? Im gettin the error message:

> The IDbCommand and IDbConnection
>   implementation in the assembly
>   MySql.Data could not be found. Ensure
>   that the assembly MySql.Data is
>   located in the application directory
>   or in the Global Assembly Cache. If
>   the assembly is in the GAC, use
>    element in the
>   application configuration file to
>   specify the full name of the assembly.

So, I added this lines to web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <qualifyAssembly partialName="MySql.Data" fullName="MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
```

But didn't worked.

This is the method who configures the Hibernate:

```
  private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {    
        return new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration()
            .Configure( @"C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Atendimento\NHibernateLayer\hibernate.cfg.xml" ) 
            .AddAssembly( typeof( NHibernateHelper ).Assembly )
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

Anyone??? Tkhs!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember seeing this error message before, and the solution that worked for me (if memory serves!) was found in this [blog entry](http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2010/02/14/Configuring-NHibernate-to-use-MySql-e28093-and-the-small-runtime-gotcha!.aspx).

You appear to be adding the appropriate line to your `web.config`, however have you verified that you're setting the correct version number / public key token?

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <qualifyAssembly partialName="MySql.Data" 
          fullName="MySql.Data, Version=6.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
   </qualifyAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

That said - I've seen strange/confusing things happen when there's `Version N` of the MySql.Data assembly in the GAC and you have another copy that you're referencing that's `Version M`. Make sure that you're referencing the *same* version in your project as is the version in the GAC.

Comment: Man, was write. I didn't believed that a simple '0' in "Version=6.3.6.0" would break it. I putted the '0' and worked. I choosed your answer as acepted because the blog has a trick to know the PublicKey Token. (The 'gacutil /l MySql.Data' command). Tks man.

Comment: @Thiago, not a problem, glad I could help =)